# Wordpress Multisite with nginx. Match subdirectories within location

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have multiple WordPress sites running in subdirectories.

Everything works great, but I'm looking to simplify my nginx configuration.

At the moment, when I add a location, I need to add an entry to my server {} configuration for the specified directory.

```
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$args;
    }

    location /site1 {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php?q=$args;
    }

    location /site2 {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/index.php?q=$args;
    }

    location /site2 {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /site3/index.php?q=$args;
    }

    location /site4 {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /site4/index.php?q=$args;
    }
```

I tried adding a regex to match the subdirectory, but seem to have a problem with it.

```
  location /([_-0-9a-zA-Z]/?) {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /$1index.php?q=$args;
  }
```

does not appear to do the trick. In theory that should match a subdirectory, or nothing, and be able to let me add new directories without having to touch the nginx configuration.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

@jedifans pointed out how to get the regex to work

Thanks. That did the trick on any pages, but when I go to / it just tries to download the index.php.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;

  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php70;
  fastcgi_keep_conn on;
}

location ~ ^/([_\-0-9a-zA-Z]*/?) {
  try_files /$1$uri /$1$uri/ /$1index.php?q=$args;
}
```

However when I go to domain.com/site1/ i get a download of the index.php not the homepage. What's missing?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the following from your new location block, the ~ operator that says to nginx that it's a regular expression. Try:

```
  location ~ ^/([_-0-9a-zA-Z]*/?) {
```

A few regex tweaks too, ^ to say it must begin with / and * to match more than one of those characters within [ and ]

Edit: after your question update, try the following try_files directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?q=$args;
```

$uri should work without the matched string prepended and I have added a / in between the matched query and the index.php;

Also make sure to have `index index.php;` at `server{}` level.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick on any pages, but when I go to / it just tries to download the index.php. I've updated the question.